# Dual Boot Windows 8 and Ubuntu: Grub works, Ubuntu boots, Windows 8 doesn't

Tags: 12.04, installation, dual-boot, windows-8

I had Win8 installed on my computer and needed to install Ubuntu, so I took a distro and created a live usb pen and installed it. Everything went fine, well not at first because my computer comes with secure boot, but in the end it was done 0 errors.

I have grub working now with ubuntu and windows 8 options. I ran boot-repair to fix my problem and it just added another windows 8 option to boot (one on sda3 another on sda4). So the probem is: in either windows 8 grub options, it starts to load normally, then when it should appear the login screen, a blue screen comes up and says a problem occurred and it reboots.

I hope you can help, thank you for your time!

Ps.: I had the exact same problem when I was trying to install Ubuntu and I solved it by deleting the partitions where I was supposed to install Ubuntu. Now I don't want to do it because Ubuntu is now successfully installed in those partitions (ext4 + swap)